# Finding Out Which Elements Are in the Viewport in Dojo

Tags: ajax, dojo, jquery-waypoints

I would like to fire a function when a user is scrolling and reaches a certain element, so that I can mark that element "read" (think of how posts were marked read after viewing them in the now defunct Google Reader). So, for example, imagine a page like the following:

```
<div id="1">Node 1</div>
<div id="2">Node 2</div>
<div id="3">Node 3</div>
<div id="4">Node 4</div>
```

Assuming only the first two `<divs>` fit within the viewport, I would like to use Dojo's event listener and fire an event when div 3 came into view and again when div 4 came into view. (In addition to my goal of recording when an element has been read, this would also allow me to easily implement infinite scrolling.)

The [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) tool seems to do exactly what I want, but since most of my code uses Dojo, I really don't want to use jQuery just for this one task. I'd like to find a prewritten tool or simple method for doing this that isn't dependent on a library/toolkit *other* than Dojo (I'm fine with it using Dojo or no library at all).

**UPDATE:** It appears [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) also does what I am looking for, but only for animation -- that is, it can animate an element based on its relationship to the viewport. This doesn't exactly help, though, since my goal isn't animation but to activate a function (that will make an AJAX call via Dojo) when an element comes within the viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a few pointers from a friend, I was able to put together a functional solution to this question. Assuming all the divs are within another div with the id articles, when the user scrolls the bottom of the element at least 50px into the viewport, I then apply a "read" class to the element.

```
    posts = dojo.query("#articles > div");

    dojo.connect(window, 'onscroll', function(){
        var vs = win.getBox();

        var output;
        var readCount;

        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            var includeScroll = false;
            var locInfo = domGeom.position(posts[i], includeScroll)
            var fullyOnScreen = locInfo.y + locInfo.h + 50;
            if ((fullyOnScreen > 0) && (fullyOnScreen < vs.h)) {
                //Apply "read" class to div if it has been scrolled to.

                domClass.add(posts[i], "read");             
            }
            if (locInfo.y > vs.h) {
                break;
            }
        }   


    });
```

Remaining question: While this solves my goal, I'm not sure it is the most efficient to poll the location of every div in or above the viewport every time the user scrolls -- even multiple times per scroll event. Are there ways to make this more efficient? It seems to run OK on my Core 2 Duo system, but I don't want to be sloppy just because it doesn't seem laggy.

I thought about calculating the position of all of the divs from the absolute top just once on start up and then doing some comparisons between the viewport and the top each time I scroll. This would probably be more efficient, but I'm not sure if the efficiency gains justify the added complexity of the code.